# VBA using Excel version of Find on a Word Object?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find the first two dates in a Word document save them as variables in an Excel macro. Other parts of my project require this to be written as an Excel macro.

```
Dim wordObj As New Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As New Word.Document
Dim Rng As Range
Dim myDate As String
Dim Fnd As Boolean
Dim i As Long
i=0
Set wordDoc = wordObj.Documents.Open(path)
Set Rng = wordDoc.Range
Do While i < 2
    With Rng.Find
        .Execute FindText:="??/??/????", MatchWildcards:=True
        Fnd = .Found                                                             
    End With
    If Fnd = True Then
        mydate = Rng
        If i = 0 Then 
            firstdate = mydate
        ElseIf i = 1 Then
            seconddate = mydate
        End If
    End If
    i = i+1
Loop
End Function
```

I get Compile Error: Argument not optional. 
The issue is, VBA is interpreting it as Excels' .Find with arguments(Target, StartLine, StartColumn... etc), instead of a Word Find object. I am new to VBA, and managing the different types of applications is a little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

> *The issue is, VBA is interpreting it as Excels' .Find with arguments(Target, StartLine, StartColumn... etc), instead of a Word Find object*
>
> ```
> Dim Rng As Range
> ```

But it *is* an Excel `Range` with a `Find` method ;-)

This line would be throwing a *type mismatch* error at run-time:

> ```
> Set Rng = wordDoc.Range
> ```

Qualify it with the library you're pulling type from:

```
Dim Rng As Word.Range
```

That will help VBA understand where that `Range` interface comes from.

---

If you look at the VBA project's references, you'll see why:

[image: VBE references dialog showing Word library priority 5 and Excel priority 2]

When VBA encounters this instruction at compile-time:

```
Dim Rng As Range
```

It needs to bind this `Range` type to a specific type. Maybe there's a `Range` user-defined-type (UDT) in the VBA project? Or a class by that name? Assuming there's none of that, then VBA tries to locate the type in the referenced libraries - *in priority order*. The VBA standard library can't be moved or removed. The host application's object model library neither.

If we search for "range" in the VBE's *object browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd>), we see that there are two classes by that name:

[image: object browser listing Excel.Range and Word.Range classes]

Therefore, because the `Excel` library comes first in the priority order when VBA is resolving the name `Range`, it binds to `Excel.Range` at compile-time.

By explicitly qualifying types with the library they're meant to be pulled from, we fix the ambiguous type reference, and VBA binds to `Word.Range` as intended.

[image: member list for a Word.Find object]